# ListView обновление данных

Tags: android, eclipse

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, беру данные из базы данных при помощи SimpleAdapter и отоброжаю в ListView, после чего заношу новые данные в базу, подскажите как обновить данные в ListView.

Comment: А каким образом вносятся изменения в базу? Какими-то внешними туалми или из самого приложения?

Comment: SqlDB dbh = new SqlDB(this);
dbh.openDatabase();
dbh.exec("INSERT INTO schet (_id, naimen, vid_schet) VALUES ('"+prefName+"', '"+naimen.getText()+"', '"+vid_schet.getSelectedItem()+"')");

Comment: может быть дело в том что это делается из разных классов?

Answer (score 7):

У адаптера нужно вызвать метод [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). В результате адаптер должен "перечитать" данные.

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал так:

```
    List<Phonebook> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
    for(int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++)
    {
        listOfPhonebook.add(new Phonebook(phones[i],numbers[i]));
    }
    PhonebookAdapter adapter = new PhonebookAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Брал прочитанный масив, и в цикле набивал им листы телефонной книги, далее его к адаптеру.

Comment: я делаю вот так
adapter12 = new SimpleAdapter(this, createSensorsList(), ndroid.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
new String[] {"title"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter12);

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло только создание нового адаптера после добавления данных(вплоть до того, что просто скопировать код твоего адаптера в место после, того, где добавляешь данные). Тоже перелазил всю сеть)